# CSS Parsing errors

Tags: css, csslint

I am using [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net) to detect errors and warnings in a specific css.
CSS Lint detects 3 errors:

[image]

in below piece of css code:

```
a.btn,
:not(li.menu_icon a.btn),
.k-button.btn,
input[type=submit].btn, 
input[type=button].btn, 
button[type=submit].btn:not(.gridAddBtn), 
button[type=button].btn:not(.gridAddBtn), 
a[name=butonWorkFlow].btn {
    background-image: none;
    min-width: 90px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

...but I do not know how to correct it. I have basic knowledge about css.

Comment: You probably have an error before the snippet you posted.

Comment: @D.Pardal I have discarded this because I have only parsed the css code before this one and there are no errors. Line indicated by CSS Lint corresponds to :not(li.menu_icon a.btn) in that piece of code.

Comment: There are no errors on your posted CSS. The lint program is probably wrong. The only issue from the W3C CSS validation is unrecognised vendor extension for `-moz-` and `-webkit-` which you don't need for `box-sizing`, to be honest.

Comment: FYI: The W3C CSS Validator (https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) marks `:not(li.menu_icon a.btn)` as a parse error here, when validating against profile `CSS level 3 + SVG`.

Comment: @CBroe: I don't recommend using Jigsaw to check CSS anymore, it's buggy, slow to catch up (or refuses to catch up with anything the maintainers don't consider a "standard" regardless of how stable or widely used the feature is), and it's been that way for *years*. Everyone uses stylelint these days.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for the info, I’ll take that into consideration in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Lint is no longer being updated, so does not recognize the updated `:not()` syntax. Use an up-to-date linter, such as [stylelint](https://stylelint.io), which will pass your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

**:not(selector)** is part of CSS3. Might be you are using lower version.

Comment: CSS Lint recognizes the old :not() syntax just fine, it's the new syntax that it doesn't understand. The highest version of CSS Lint is several years old. Nobody uses it anymore.